# Using the MONTH function with in a joined query

Tags: mysql, database

I have MySQL joined query which I need to use the MONTH() function.  Currently if I use this query it properly returns a value

```
    SELECT logins.`Client`, paths.`CommunityName` FROM `Actions` actions, `Logins` logins, `Paths` paths WHERE logins.Id = actions.LoginId AND actions.Name = 'beginTagSession' AND paths.Id = actions.CurrentPathId AND actions.`Date` = Date(NOW());
```

But what I need it to do is return values based on a specific month.  The following query returns an error.

```
    SELECT logins.`Client`, paths.`CommunityName` FROM `Actions` actions, `Logins` logins, `Paths` paths WHERE logins.Id = actions.LoginId AND actions.Name = 'beginTagSession' AND paths.Id = actions.CurrentPathId AND actions.MONTH(`Date`) = 4;
```

Using the MONTH() function in previous queries seems to work properly

```
    SELECT `Client` FROM Logins WHERE MONTH(Date) =  4 ORDER BY `Date` ASC";
```

So I am not exactly sure how to get around it.  The error says "Function actions.MONTH does not exist"

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think you want: "MONTH(actions.`Date`) = 4"

Comment: Yes!  Thank you, that was it.  Was driving me crazy